# Open url in same tab in browser using android code(not using webview)

Tags: android, cordova

I am trying to open URL in browser in same tab. Instead of creating new tab(for same URL) of each click on android app.

Hers's is the code:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,Uri.parse("http://1.1.1.1:8008"));
intent.putExtra(Browser.EXTRA_APPLICATION_ID, "com.android.browser");
startActivity(intent);
```

If I close the browser and again restart the application I see URL opened in new tab, instead of open using existing tab.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Web browsers available for Android. Whether a browser even *offers* tabs to the user is up to the developers of the browser. For those that do offer tabs, how the browser handles `ACTION_VIEW` requests with respect to those tabs is also up to the developers of the browser.

There is nothing in the standard `ACTION_VIEW` protocol to say "please put this in an existing tab", largely because few things that support `ACTION_VIEW` have tabs.

It is certainly possible that some browsers offer some extra to control tab behavior with respect to `ACTION_VIEW`. You are welcome to contact the developers of those browsers and ask them.